# How to create new unique id every time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've multiple modals in my single page.

I've HTML and JavaScript of modal. Currently, it has only one same id but I want to make it dynamic. Every time it generates a new id.

How to create new unique id every time in JavaScript?

**HTML**

```
<button class="trigger" id="trigger">Share</button> 
<div class="modal" id="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close-button" id="close-button">×</span>
<h5>Share</h5>
</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function toggleModal() {
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}

function windowOnClick(event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
        toggleModal();
    }
}
trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

Help me to get out from this problem changing unique id in JavaScript

Comment: You mean like `var modal = document.querySelector("#modal");`?

Comment: if you are using ids then why do you need query selectors?
By default id is unique even if you declare it multiple time then also your first element will only be selected.
Since you need to perform event on specific id, use `$('#id')` in jQuery *or* `document.getElementByID('id')` in JavaScript

Comment: @Rnayak I've multiple modals with the same id

Comment: instead of `id` then use `class`
and use `querySelector` for getting modals
And for generating unique ids you can try something like setting id value to `id + lengthofModalArray` return by querySelector
It will always generate new id and you can keep track of total modals too.

Comment: The point with the id is that it should be unique.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why do you want to change to using id instead of class ? What benefit do you expect, or which problem do you want to solve ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use either:

```js
var modal = document.querySelector("#modal");
```

If you want to stick to `querySelector`. Or you can use:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
```

Which should be slightly faster.

`querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` accept all valid CSS selectors. More information about CSS selectors is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Comment: *"Which should be slightly faster."* Heh, or even **dramatically** faster. :-) Not that it usually matters these days, but...

Comment: Doesn't really matter but it's worth a mention.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if only called 3 times, I would not say **dramatically** faster, even in the old days.

Comment: @appleapple - Oh, it's always dramatically faster. It's just that (as I said) it almost never matters, and (as you said) certainly not if only being called three times. But parsing a CSS selector takes time. I remember being really struck by the delta when I measured it a couple of years ago...

Answer (score 2):

Just replace each

`.querySelector(".myclass");`

by

`.querySelector("#myid");`

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use a library that called UUID

1  Install in TERMINAL:  npm install UUID --save

2  import in js file codes : import UUID from 'uuid/v1'

3  use: it can be used everywhere in code for generating a unique id, for the examination you can use console log (UUID()), in the inspect you will observe a new unique code each time that console log had used.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [cuid](https://github.com/ericelliott/cuid) library, and then use as below

1. install it via npm `npm install --save cuid` and use as below

   import cuid from 'cuid';

   console.log( cuid() );

// cjld2cjxh0000qzrmn831i7rn

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple modals on the page and you want to generate a unique ID for each of these modals, you can follow the example below.

```
const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

modals.forEach(function (item , index) {
    item.id = 'modal-' + parseFloat(index+1);
})
```